# Prevent custom AccessoryView from showing selection when it's UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

To reproduce this, create a UITableView that contains cells with custom AccessoryViews (such as buttons to perform a specific action where touching the other part of the UITableViewCell should perform a different action).

If you touch (select) the UITableView, the AccessoryView shows selection (as thought it was touched) as well. I want to prevent this and only show the AccessoryView's selected state when they actually touch the AccessoryView.

Thanks in advance,

groomsy

Comment: Would you post a picture of behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is that the accessory view – let's say it's a button – displays its selected state not only when the button is tapped, but when the row itself is selected. The asker wants the accessory button only to show its selected state when it is directly tapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass? I would try doing so and overriding 
`setSelected:(BOOL)selected` for that class to make sure things are handled as you want.

Comment: Overriding this and ensuring the button had setSelected:NO and setHighlighted:NO worked. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work because the selection still flashes for a fraction of a second looking ugly.

Comment: @Lee It might also be necessary to override setHighlighted:. I'm not totally clear on the relationship between those two methods, but both seem to be involved in the selection process.

Comment: @CharlieMezak - Since I already had created a custom tableViewCell I tried setting the cell's selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.  This works perfectly without any flash.  Thanks for reply though.

Answer (score 5):

When UIButton is set as the accessoryView of a UITableViewCell, setHighlighted will be called for the accessoryView (the UIButton in this case) when its superview (the UITableViewCell) is selected.

To fix this, we need to subclass UIButton, override its setHighlighted setter to ignore if its superview isSelected or isHighlighted.

**AccessoryViewUIButton.m**

```
#import "AccessoryViewUIButton.h"


@implementation AccessoryViewUIButton

// Subclass only works for buttonWithType:custom

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer 
    self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];

    return self;
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)isHighlighted {

    /* Overridden to do nothing if superview is selected or highlighted */

    UITableViewCell* theCell = (UITableViewCell*) self.superview;

    if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        if ([theCell isSelected] || [theCell isHighlighted])
            return;
    }

    [super setHighlighted:isHighlighted];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessory View would not glow or show selection when the table cell is tapped. I think you want the tableViewCell's blue color selection state to not be visible on the accessoryViews background. is that correct?

I would suggest creating your own custom tableViewCell and setting the cell's selectionStyle to  `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` and handling the tableRowSelection to setSelected state for the cell side alone and not the accessory view.

or just make the accessory view's background a little larger and dont set it backgroundColor to clearColor. that way the selection state of the cell wont be shown on the accessoryView as well.

Comment: When you have a custom view set as the accessory view for a UITableViewCell, the accessory view *is* shown as selected when the table cell is selected or highlighted. You can try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the table view cell, and override the following methods:

```
- (void) setHighlighted: (BOOL) highlighted;
- (void) setHighlighted: (BOOL) highlighted
               animated: (BOOL) animated;
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected;
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected
            animated: (BOOL) animated;
```

and make sure the button's `selected` *and* `highlighted` states are reset to `NO` after calling the superclass method.